# Spring Boot Application Error

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, dependency-management

I am doing my first project with Spring Boot. I am getting the below error which I do not have clue about.Am I missing any dependency in build.gradle shown below?I am getting the error when I am running the Application.java file.

```
    org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at com.bale.route.Application.main(Application.java:12) [classes/:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:185) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        ... 8 common frames omitted
```

Below are my configuration files.

```
    **//Application.java**

        package com.test.route;

        import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

        import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
        import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
        import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

        @SpringBootApplication
        public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
            }
            protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(

                    SpringApplicationBuilder application) {

                return application.sources

    (Application.class);

        }
    }
```

**//build.gradle**

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE")
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'war'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'spring-boot'



    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7

    dependencies {
         compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
         {

            exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'


        }



        // tag::actuator[]
        //compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
        compile("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core")
        // end::actuator[]
        // tag::tests[]
        //testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
        // end::tests[]
    }

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '2.3'
    }
```

**//application.properties**

```
    server.servlet-path= /app
    logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
    spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
    spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
    cookie.path=
    cookie.domain=
```

What am I missing in my configuration?

Comment: You shouldn't exclude `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` . Remove the exlude and explicit declaration of the `tomcat-embed-core`.

Answer (score 1):

I see, you've excluded `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` from `spring-boot-starter-web` for some reason and added `org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core` as dependency.

According to the exception, you don't have a bean `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory`. It seems to me, that this bean (exact `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory`) is created in some configuration within `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency. So it seems, that you have to leave `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` or you will have to create this bean by your self.

Comment: Thanks for your response,Stanislav. But I still get the same error even though I comment out the exclude.

Comment: Could you tell, how do you run it? As standalone jar or as deployable war?

Comment: I run it as a standalone jar. I run the Application.java file(shown above) as a java application.

Comment: in that case you don't need to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`. It's needed only for deployable war creation

Comment: Do you mean to say if I run it as deployable war, the application will work fine.